# User Must Take Action for Page Redirection to Work in Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I have a `/map` route in my Flask app. In this map, when an object is selected, a button is shown to redirect to the next page (let's call it `/demo`). Currently this demo page is accessible by everyone if you type in the url as `www.mysite.com/demo`.

**How can I make it so that the user *must* select an object on the `/map` page first in order to be allowed access on the `/demo` page?**

When you select an object in the map, a GET request is fired:

**Flask**:

```
@app.route('/getID', methods=['GET'])
def getID():
    ID = float(request.args.get("ID",""))
    objectCollection = db["objects"]

    for object in objectCollection.find({"properties.ID":ID},{"properties.ID":1,"properties.Address":1,"_id":0}).limit(1):
        return jsonify(selectedObject=object)
```

**JS**:

```
var objectIDClick = event.feature.getProperty('ID');
$.ajax({
    url: '/getID?' + 'ID=' + objectIDClick,
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function (data) { ... }
});
```

If a user tries to access the `/demo` page without selecting an object first in the `/map` page, simply redirect them back to the `/map` page.

I know I have to use something like:

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    return redirect(url_for('demo'))
else:
    return render_template('map.html')
```

But I can't seem to put it all together. My routes are defined as follows:

```
@app.route("/map")
def map():
    return render_template("map.html")

@app.route("/demo")
def demo():
    return render_template("demo.html")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have the `/demo` page check the request's [Referer:](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.5.2) HTTP header. If the referrer isn't `/map`, then don't show the page.

Here is one implementation. For convenience, I have added the test in a Flask [view decorator](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/viewdecorators/).

This program uses Flask and html, no Javascript. You'll need to adapt it to Javascript if required.

```
from urlparse import urlparse
from functools import wraps
from flask import (
    Flask,
    redirect,
    request,
    render_template_string,
    url_for)
app = Flask(__name__)

def confirm_referrer(path, redirect_func):
    def decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kw):
            ref = urlparse(request.referrer or '')
            if (request.host, path) == (ref.netloc, ref.path):
                return f(*args, **kw)
            return redirect(url_for(redirect_func))
        return wrapper
    return decorator


@app.route('/map')
def map():
    return render_template_string('''
        <html><body>
            <p><a href="{{ url_for("demo") }}">Demonstrate</a></p>
        </body></html>''')

@app.route('/demo')
@confirm_referrer('/map', 'map')
def demo():
    return '''<p>This is a demonstration</p>'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

EDIT: Responding to new requirements.

```
from urlparse import urlparse
from functools import wraps
from flask import (
    Flask,
    redirect,
    request,
    render_template_string,
    url_for)
app = Flask(__name__)

def confirm_referrer(paths, redirect_func):
    def decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kw):
            ref = urlparse(request.referrer or '')
            if any((request.host, path) == (ref.netloc, ref.path)
                   for path in paths):
                return f(*args, **kw)
            return redirect(url_for(redirect_func))
        return wrapper
    return decorator


@app.route('/map')
def map():
    return render_template_string('''
        <html><body>
            <p><a href="{{ url_for("demo") }}">Demonstrate</a></p>
        </body></html>''')

@app.route('/map_ru')
def map_ru():
    return render_template_string(u'''
        <html><body>
            <p><a href="{{ url_for("demo") }}">
\u0434\u0435\u043c\u043e\u043d\u0441\u0442\u0440\u0438\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0430\u0442\u044c
</a></p>
        </body></html>''')

@app.route('/demo')
@confirm_referrer(['/map', '/map_ru'], 'map')
def demo():
    return '''<p>This is a demonstration</p>'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach. It makes sense. Going to try it out now and let you know. Thanks for such detailed response.

Comment: Can this work for multiple pages? For example, what if there were 2 different map pages that lead to the same destination `(/demo)`? Can I not simply repeat `@confirm_referrer` for this second map page?

Comment: That would not work as the code is structured now. One or the other of the confirm_referrer wrappers would force a redirect. If being able to recognize multiple valid referrers is a requirement, I'd pass a list into `confirm_referrers()`, and modify `confirm_referrer` to iterate over the list.